# Making a div slightly off-center

Tags: css, html

Usually I would do this by either setting the margin to auto, using position:absolute, or via padding but unfortunately these will not work in this case. I need a div to be about 15 pixels off-center horizontally from the page. The tricky bit is it needs to scale correctly as the page widens. It seems to me that I would need to do this horizontal adjustment based on the center point, rather than the left hand side. How could I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: by scale correctly you mean it has to move with the main div? or you want it to (literally) scale, for example: if the screen is 800px the space would be 15px, and if it's 1200 it'd be 22px?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a container div, which is centered, then its content you can give `margin-left:npx` - like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="green">&nbsp;</span><br />
    <span id="blue">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{width:100px; margin:auto auto; background-color:red;}
#container span{display:block; width:100%; }
#green{background-color:green; margin-left:10px;}
#blue{background-color:blue; margin-left:-10px;}
```

See the example coded up here - http://jsfiddle.net/Xpk8A/1/

Comment: So many answers! Ultimately this is the one most similar to what I did so I guess you win the prize hah. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

give a wrapper with:
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;

inside wrapper, put div:
    position:relative;
    left: -15px; (or whatever you want)

example page would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position your `div` and set the `left` attribute to 50%. Then, set the `margin-left` to 50% + 5px (whatever that is). This would only work if you have a fixed width on the box, however. For example, if the box is 200px wide, the `margin-left` would be `-115px`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set `width:100%` and a fixed `margin`, as you can see in my example below

```
<style>
div {
background-color:red;
 height:100px;
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
margin-left:15px;
}
</style>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="centered">
            <div class="offcenter">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css will be:

```
.centered
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}

.offcenter
{
    background-color:blue;
    width:285px;
    height:inherit;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evbbq/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` for `center` the `DIV` then give your `margin` to it .

Like this:

```
.Parent{text-align:center;}
.Child{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    background:red;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xpk8A/2/

*Remove `margin-left:15px` then click on `Run` button in the fiddle to see the different.*